# New record will not show up in PHPMyadmin with this code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    mysql_select_db("strsmi_database");

    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName , Lastname , AGE) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'hi', 'hello' , 2) ";
    $insert=mysql_query($sql, $con);
    if ( insert)
    {
          echo 'Table Updated' ;
    }
    else
    {   
          echo 'error' .mysql_error();
    }
    mysql_close($con);
```

Ouptput on website tells me that table has been updated but on phpMyAdmin it is not.

Comment: try removing the DEFAULT in your query. Also try using PDO or mysqli instead of mysql_* functions since they are deprecated

Comment: Default removed but still nothing

Comment: Missing `$` in `if ( insert)` change to `if ($insert)` also make sure your fields match letter-case `FirstName , Lastname , AGE` --- `Firstname` is not the same as `firstname` @StruanSmith

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually MySQL column names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Put the query manually through PHPmyadmin and see if it works or if any error messages appear.

Comment: @StruanSmith So if you have removed the extra value (DEFAULT) that you were trying to insert, and are still having problems, can you update your question to indicate what error you are now getting?

Comment: Changing misssing $ worked.

Comment: Ah, well will you lookah dat. I stand corrected (just tested on one of my tables). Thanks @MikeBrant --- However, the missing `$` in `if ( insert)` still needs to be in there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes.  You correctly called out the problem here (well in addition to the other original problem of trying to insert 4 values into 3 columns.  Just wanted to make sure the point about column name cases was presented correctly.

Comment: I for one have learned something today Mike, regarding the columns' case-insensitivity. I always thought they were. Thanks again @MikeBrant

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is somewhat odd in MySQL in that tables names may or may not be case sensitive (depending on OS, and `lower_case_table_names` setting). Column names however are always case-insensitive.  Here is more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Much appreciated Mike, reading it now. @MikeBrant - cheers

Answer (score 0):

If there is a default or a Auto increment column such as (id) you don't need to pass any values. in that case you can use.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (id, FirstName , Lastname , AGE) VALUES ( '', 'hi', 'hello' , 2) ";
```

and if you don't have a column called **id**. then you can use it like this. but all the variables in PHP must he **$** in front. so use like this **$insert**.

```
mysql_select_db("strsmi_database");

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName , Lastname , AGE) VALUES ( 'hi', 'hello' , 2) ";
$insert=mysql_query($sql, $con);
if ( $insert)
{
      echo 'Table Updated' ;
}
else
{   
      echo 'error' .mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
```